# Does ADMIN Directory have API for dealing with EMAIL Settings

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-email-settings-api

Does ADMIN Directory have API for dealing with EMAIL Settings. Or do we need to continue using GDATA API for Email Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Email Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/) is still GData based. Until it is upgraded to the new Google API model, you'll need to continue to use the GData API and libraries to access it.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I was looking deeper into the current code and I see we are using ClientLogin to Authenticate Email Settings API calls. Can we continue using ClientLogin for the old GData API Calls? When is Google planning to retire ClientLogin ?

Comment: "Important: ClientLogin has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will be shut down on April 20, 2015 as per our deprecation policy. We encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible."

Comment: Thanks AMS. We are moving to OAuth2.0 and I had tested the same and it  worked fine.